# Object oriented design in javascript and 'this' pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, this

I am creating a object in javascript like this

```
function myobject() {
   this.myvar1 = 0;
   this.myvar2 = 0;
}

myobject.prototype.a = function(){
    this.myvar1 +=1;
    $('#button').click(function () {  // 'this' is undefined
        alert(this.myvar1)
     })
}

var mything = new myobject();
mything.a()
```

What is the proper way to pass the `this` pointer to an anonymous function?

Comment: The code as written ought to work. Let's see exactly how you're calling this.b()

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ygkBP/

Comment: btw, consider capitalizing constructor function names: http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*For updated question:*
The issue is that inside that event handler, `this` refers to the element you clicked on, rather than your `myobject`, so just keep a reference to it, like this:

```
myobject.prototype.a = function(){
    this.myvar1 +=1;
    var self = this;
    $('#button').click(function () {
        alert(self.myvar1)
    });
}
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/6Ltac/).

---

*For previous question:*
What you have should work (exactly as you have it), [you can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/4Xpxk/).

Comment: I oversimplified the example.  I updated the code.  I think the problem has to do with passing the 'this' pointer to an anonymous function.

Comment: @Alexis - It's not that `this` is undefined, it just refers to the handler inside that function, just maintain a reference like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/6Ltac/

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following code to the end of your snippet and running it correctly alerts '1':

```
mything.b();
alert(mything.myvar1);
```

What were you expecting? Perhaps you're incorrectly invoking `mything.b()` ?

Comment: you're right.  In the example, I over simplified the code.  I updated the example.

Answer (score 1):

To pass `this` to an inner function, "save" it to another variable.

```
myobject.prototype.a = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.myvar1 += 1;

    $('#button').click(function () {
         alert(self.myvar1);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that jQuery is hijacking the value of `this` in the anonymous function used as a handler for the click event. It's kind of confusing, but jQuery's behavior is to assign the DOM element that triggered the event to `this`. There are a couple ways to set the value of `this` explicitly (the "context") for the callback function:

1. Function.prototype.bind - Part of the ECMAScript 5 standard, just starting to be implemented in browsers. For legacy support, you can extract it from the Prototype library.
2. $.proxy - jQuery's crappy equivalent of Function.prototype.bind, which was introduced in jQuery 1.4.

I wrote a couple posts on my blog that explain these in more detail if you're interested:

- [Organizing JavaScript with Namespaces and Function Prototypes](http://www.jimmycuadra.com/blog/15-organizing-javascript-with-namespaces-and-function-prototypes)
- [Understanding jQuery 1.4's $.proxy() method](http://www.jimmycuadra.com/blog/16-understanding-jquery-1-4-s-proxy-method)

In both cases, since `this` will now be your object and not the triggering DOM element, you can get the triggering DOM element by inspecting the event object, which will be the second parameter to your callback function.

Comment: this is a very useful answer also!

Answer (score 0):

Others here have done a nice job explaining the issue and how to resolve without adding any dependencies, but personally I think this plugin is a better overall solution (if you don't mind the dependency):

http://markdalgleish.com/projects/eventralize/